# iTunes 12: How to export podcast subscriptions

Tags: macos, itunes, podcasts, opml

With the release of iTunes 12 for Mac the option to export my podcast subscriptions (via an opml file) seems to be killed.

Is there a possibility to create an Applescript that performs this job?

Answer (score 2):

You can still export to an OPML file with a playlist:

1. Go to Library section on the top middle and make sure the Podcasts icon is selected
2. Go to File -> Library -> Export Playlist
3. In the Dialog window it will give the option at the bottom to select the OPML format

Answer (score -1):

Nope. There is no such option for OPML anywhere within the iTunes export function. It offers .xml and that's all.